# Bind AngularJS variables into CSS syntax

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to bind AngularJS scope vars into CSS syntax.
I think that the problem is in the curly braces.
Here is what I'm basically trying to do:

```
<style>.css_class {background:{{ angular_variable }}; color:#ffffff;}</style>
<style>.css_rule {background:{{ "#000000" }}; color:#ffffff;}</style>
<style>.css_rule {background:{{ var | someFilter }}; color:#ffffff;}</style>
```

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you check `ng-class` http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass . Where is this code located?

Comment: yes i know about ng-class but i need to manipulate non-dom elements like ::-webkit-scrollbar... the css code is in the html view (inside the controller scope)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As explained [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/i0UNa7OUiW0/-GoF_nUf8O4J) angular doesn't run on content inside style tags. There's a workaround plunkr in that post but as a more flexible approach I'd just create a directive that grabs the contents, parses them and replaces:

#### Updated answer

```
app.directive('parseStyle', function($interpolate) {
    return function(scope, elem) {
        var exp = $interpolate(elem.html()),
            watchFunc = function () { return exp(scope); };

        scope.$watch(watchFunc, function (html) {
            elem.html(html);
        });
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<style parse-style>.css_class {color: {{ angular_variable }};}</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VUeGG/31/

---

#### Original answer

```
app.directive('parseStyle', function()
{
    return function(scope, elem)
    {
        elem.html(scope.$eval('\'' + elem.html() + '\''));
    };
});
```

then:

```
<style parse-style>.css_class {color: ' + angular_variable + ';}</style>
```

Not sure about the browser support for this though.

http://jsfiddle.net/VUeGG/4/

Comment: I just added a major refactor of this awesome code below. Thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: @Campbeln it's the right idea, but you can do away with the parsing by using $interpolate. In fact, I don't know why I didn't use it in the first place. See updated answer

Comment: I've taken this and run with it and the result is an Angular "plugin" (module+filters+factory) [called ngCss](http://opensourcetaekwondo.com/ngcss/) that handles this and much more - [check it out](http://github.com/campbeln/ngcss)!

Comment: @jonnyynnoj this is a great answer, is there a way to easily adapt this to inline script?  eg I tried <script parse-style>console.log('{{angular_variable}}');</script> but this returns {{angular_variable}}

Comment: @jonnyynnoj would this still work if I am trying to list several items which have the same class, but need to have different values for one of the CSS properties, say, background-color?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't see why not, just use `ng-style` to set the separate property

Comment: What do you mean by that? I thought the idea was to use the custom directive above?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well it depends. I meant if you're wanting to set an individual color for each item in a list you can just set it as an inline style via `ng-style`, it's not something you'd need to use a class for. Maybe I'm not following what you mean.

Comment: @jonnyynnoj, You are understanding me correctly. The problem is that I am using this  open-source calendar which only allows a certain customization through a class. Hence, I was trying to keep the name of the class the same but change a property  inside for each item. I am not even sure if that is possible ...

Comment: So with the combination of `ngInclude` and standard `<style></style>` it all works perfectly fine without any extra directives.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

I've put together an Angular "plugin" (module+filters+factory) [called ngCss](http://opensourcetaekwondo.com/ngcss/) that handles this and much more - [check it out](http://github.com/campbeln/ngcss)!

I also have made a Vanilla Javascript (e.g. no external dependencies) version as well; [CjsSS.js](http://opensourcetaekwondo.com/cjsss/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/campbeln/CjsSS.js)).

> **ngCss** is a tiny* Angular Module+Factory+Filters that enables binding of strings and objects (including nested objects) within CSS.
>   *Minified+compressed script under 1,700 bytes
>
> **Features:**
>
> - CSS can be live-bound (changes in `$scope` are `$watch`'ed) or updated via the custom `$broadcast` event updateCss.
> - css and cssInline Filters output Javascript/JSON `objects` as CSS to enable mixins, including the ability to nest `objects`.
> - `$scope` can be initialized within the CSS itself, allowing for all CSS-related information to be co-located within the *.css or STYLE element.
> - `$scope` can be isolated or imported from any Angular `$element` (via `angular.element($element).scope()`).

**Original**
Thanks to @jonnyynnoj's code I've figured out a way to keep the `{{angular_variable}}` nomenclature within the style tags as well as live binding any changes. [Check out the fork of @jonnyynnoj's code](http://jsfiddle.net/b9or22ux/5/) for a simple example or have a look below at what I'm using in my apps:

```
(function (ngApp) {
    'use strict';

    //# Live bind a <style cn-styler="{ commented: true, usingSingleQuote: true }" /> tag with {{ngVars}}
    ngApp.directive('cnStyler', function () {
        return {
            //# .restrict the directive to attribute only (e.g.: <style cn-styler>...</style>)
            restrict: "A",
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, controllers) {
                //# .$eval the in-line .options and setup the updateCSS function
                //#     NOTE: The expected string value of the inline options specifies a JSON/JavaScript object, hence the `|| {}` logic
                var css, regEx,
                    options = $scope.$eval($attrs["cnStyler"]) || {},
                    updateCSS = function () {
                        //# .$eval the css, replacing the results back into our $element's .html
                        $element.html($scope.$eval(css));
                    }
                ;

                //# Setup the .quote and the inverse in .unquote (which we use to process the css)
                //#     NOTE: In theory, the .unquote should not be present within the css
                options.quote = (options.usingSingleQuote !== false ? "'" : '"');
                options.unquote = (options.quote === '"' ? "'" : '"');
                regEx = new RegExp(options.unquote, "g");

                //# Process the $element's .html into css, .replace'ing any present .unquote's with .quote's (this could cause problems), then the {{Angular}} (or /*{{Angular}}*/) variables with ' + stringified_versions + '
                if (options.commented !== false) {
                    css = options.unquote + ($element.html() + '')
                        .replace(regEx, options.quote)
                        .replace(/\/\*{{/g, options.unquote + "+")
                        .replace(/}}\*\//g, "+" + options.unquote)
                    + options.unquote;
                } else {
                    css = options.unquote + ($element.html() + '')
                        .replace(regEx, options.quote)
                        .replace(/{{/g, options.unquote + "+")
                        .replace(/}}/g, "+" + options.unquote)
                    + options.unquote;
                }

                //# .$watch for any changes in the $scope, calling our updateCSS function when they occur
                $scope.$watch(updateCSS);
            }
        };
    });

})(YOUR_NG_APP_VAR_HERE);
```

Then you use this directive like this:

```
<style cn-styler type="text/css">
    .myClass{
        color: /*{{themeColor}}*/;
    }
</style>
```

Where you have set `$scope.themeColor` somewhere in your controller and you've replaced `YOUR_NG_APP_VAR_HERE` with your `ngApp` variable.

**NOTES:**

Make sure that your `ng-controller` is defined with scope to the `<style>` tag as `<style>` tag's should be in the `<head>` while `ng-controller` is generally defined on the `<body>` tag or below. **TL;DR:** Put your `ng-controller` on your `<html>` tag like so:

```
<html ng-app="YOUR_NG_APP_VAR_HERE" ng-controller="MyNgController">
```

Due to CSS parsing and auto-formatting in tools like *Visual Studio* I added the feature to have the `{{Angular}}` vars within CSS comments (e.g. `/*{{Angular}}*/`). **This is the default behavior** of the directive unless you override it like so:

```
<style cn-styler="{commented: false}" >...</style>
```

Due to the nature of this solution (the CSS is `.$eval`uated as a string with variables inserted within), the presence of single or double quotes within the CSS also needs to be processed. By default, the directive assumes you are using single quotes (') within your CSS which means in order to avoid any introduced errors **you should only use single quotes within your CSS** as any double quotes present within the CSS will be replaced with single quotes. You can override this default behavior (meaning you're using double quotes within your CSS) like so:

```
<style cn-styler="{usingSingleQuote: false}" >...</style>
```

There are edge cases where the replacing of double quotes with single quotes screws up the CSS (such as in `content`), so you will want to ensure that you are only using one style of quotes in your CSS (and signaling the directive accordingly) to avoid any potential issues. Thankfully quotes are rarely used in CSS so this is mostly a non-issue.

Comment: upvoting for the first note, that was missing from my html, style was defined above controller. thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the curly braces as these are being evaluated inside html directive - you only need to use the curly braces if you have an expression that is evaluated outside of them ie;

```
<p ng-class="some-angular-variable">
  {{some-angular-variable}}
</p>
```

In your situation, removing the double-curly braces and using double-quotes should solve the problem.

As an aside, Chandermani is on the money - what you are trying to is better accomplished with the ng-class directive. Using it will allow to apply a class (or several) to the corresponding tag.

ie;

```
<p ng-class="mystyle">
    some text
</p>
```

say you have two classes style1 and style2

You can select whichever one to apply with

```
scope.mystyle = "style1" // or whatever
```

in your controller.

Comment: i need to apply an "unknown" color that will come in later.. so classes are not relevant here.. plus, i cannot apply the ng-class / ng-style attributes to non dom element like ::-webkit-scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why u want use thid idea!
U should use ng-class for that!

For example:

```
<p ng-class="{strike: strike, bold: bold, red: red}">Map Senter code hereyntax Example</p>
```

Comment: Because i need to manipulate non dom elements like the scroll bar with a color that comes from outside source