# Angularjs Bind variables into external css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope

i'm trying to figure out how to bind angularjs scope vars into external css file the problem i think is the curly braces here is what i'm basically trying to do:

```
.css_class {background:{{ angular_variable }}; color:#ffffff;}
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248437/angularjs-bind-variables-into-css-syntax) but the solution corresponds to inline css, but what if we need to externalize the template and the css properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid at the moment that is not possible but last commit for angularjs added support for expresssions in style tags.

So you can do things like that:

In your controller:

```
$Scope.mystyles = {
 .myclass: {
  display: block
 }
};
```

In your html:

```
<style>{{mystyles}}</style>
```

[angularjs changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Take into account that it won't work in IE8 though, since it's been deprecated from 1.3.x.

Comment: Well frankly not bothered about IE but it still feels a hack, though thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[You could likely use this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248437/angularjs-bind-variables-into-css-syntax/26172468#26172468) ([and this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9or22ux/5/)) coupled with an AJAX request to pull the external CSS code into a variable, process it, then `.append` a new `<script>` tag into the DOM with the processed contents.

EDIT: Wow, this has been a month-long journey!

I've put together a Angular "plugin" (module+filters+factory) [called ngCss](http://opensourcetaekwondo.com/ngcss/) that handles this and much more - [check it out](http://github.com/campbeln/ngcss)!

Answer (score 0):

how about keeping static css in external css file, and bind dynamic css using ng-style?

External css file:

```
.css_class {color:#ffffff;}
```

In your html:

```
<div class="css_class" ng-style="{ background: angular_variable }" ></div>
```