# Using angularjs template {{ }} inside css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/helpme128/rba7zqzn/

Inside the jsfiddle, the CSS looks like this;

```
#container {
   width : auto;
   height: 1200px;
   background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgZvy.jpg');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

I would like to modify this jsfiddle such that the css can look more angular like;

```
#container {
   width : auto;
   height: 1200px;
    background:url({{backgroundURL}});
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Inside the controller, there would be a line like this;

```
$scope.backgroundURL = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgZvy.jpg';
```

How can this be done with angularjs inside css?

Comment: Hey, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248437/bind-angularjs-variables-into-css-syntax

Comment: how about instead of using that you just add an attribute class or id. that calls for the background.

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone', could you give some code example? Sorry, I don't quite follow.

Comment: you could  target  the elem.style.background directly

Comment: @maioman, sorry, I am new to web apis. would you mind providing some code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `style` attribute as following:

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div id="container" style="background: url({{backgroundUrl}})">
        <div class="shape" ng-draggable='dragOptions' ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and set the value in your controller as following:

```
angular.module('test').controller('testCtrl', function($scope) { 
    $scope.backgroundUrl = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgZvy.jpg';
 })
```

Check the fiddle link here https://jsfiddle.net/rba7zqzn/5/

Answer (score 2):

something like this.

```
<div class="ng-class: expression;"></div>
```

here's a link for you to check:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="{{backgroundURL}}">
    <p>asdfasdfasdf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mybg {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgZvy.jpg');
  }
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.backgroundURL = "mybg";
  }]);
```

Comment: Sorry, what I want is to have {{ }} inside the css and the contents of {{ }} taken from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

As `ng-src` is angular's in-built directive, you can use a custom directive which provides background for the div  as below , moreover with isolate scope u can reuse the directive wherever required.

**controller**

```
 $scope.backgroundURL = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgZvy.jpg';
```

**template**

```
<div background-url="backgroundURL"></div>
```

**directive**

```
     app.directive('backgroundUrl',function(){
          return{
              restrict:"A",// used as attribute in template
              link :function(scope,element,attrs){
                    var backgroundurl = attrs.backgroundUrl;
                    element.css('background','url(' + backgroundurl +')');
                }
          }
      })
```